# Swagger.ObjectModel.Builders.RequiredFieldException: 'Paths' is required

Tags: asp.net, swagger, swagger-ui, nancy

Using Nancy v 1.4.1 and Nancy.Swagger v 2.1.1 (the last one that supports Nancy v1), I get the above error when navigating to the /api-docs path. Any ideas? No setup steps I've seen says anything about the 'Paths' field.

My Module:

```
public class General : NancyModule
{
    public General()
    {


        Get["/","Home"] = parameters =>
        {
            try
            {
                return "home";// View["view/index.html"];
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return ExceptionHelper.ExceptionResponse(Negotiate, ex);
            }
        };

        Get["/test/", "Test"] = parameters => {
            return "testie";
        };
    }
}
```

My Module metadata:

```
public class GeneralMetadataModule : MetadataModule<PathItem>
{
    public GeneralMetadataModule(ISwaggerModelCatalog modelCatalog)
    {
        Describe["Test"] = description => description.AsSwagger(
            with => with.Operation(
                op => op.OperationId("Test")
                        .Tag("Users")
                        .Summary("The list of users")
                        .Description("This returns a list of users from our awesome app")));
    }
}
```

Stack Trace:

> Nancy.RequestExecutionException: Oh noes! ---> Swagger.ObjectModel.Builders.RequiredFieldException: 'Paths' is required.
>      at Swagger.ObjectModel.Builders.SwaggerRootBuilder.Build() in C:\projects\nancy-swagger\src\Swagger.ObjectModel\Builders\SwaggerRootBuilder.cs:line 123
>      at Nancy.Swagger.Services.SwaggerMetadataProvider.GetSwaggerJson() in C:\projects\nancy-swagger\src\Nancy.Swagger\Services\SwaggerMetadataProvider.cs:line 91
>      at Nancy.Swagger.Modules.SwaggerModule.<>c__DisplayClass0_0.<.ctor>b__0(Object _) in C:\projects\nancy-swagger\src\Nancy.Swagger\Modules\SwaggerModule.cs:line 11
>      at CallSite.Target(Closure , CallSite , Func`2 , Object )
>      at Nancy.Routing.Route.<>c__DisplayClass4.b__3(Object parameters, CancellationToken context)
>      --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
>      at Nancy.NancyEngine.InvokeOnErrorHook(NancyContext context, ErrorPipeline pipeline, Exception ex)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have it in wrong order - name should be first, then path

```
Get["Home", "/"] = parameters =>  //this is right
{
    try
    {
        return "home";// View["view/index.html"];
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        return ExceptionHelper.ExceptionResponse(Negotiate, ex);
    }
};

Get["Test", "/test/"] = parameters => {  //and this is right
    return "testie";
};
```

Comment: Thanks. Wish you were here a month ago LOL

Answer (score 0):

Well, so anyway it turns out that you need to do this:

```
public class General : NancyModule
{
    public General() : base("/v1/general/")//this part
    {
        ...
    {
}
```

Even though the sample nancy.swagger projects don't actually do it and still function for some reason. Anyway, inheriting base(path) sorted it out for me.